# How do I validate that two values do not equal each other in a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have a User model, which has an email and a password field. For security, these may not be equal to each other. How can I define this in my model?

Comment: That's weird why later answer was accepted while others are nearly the same?

Comment: @Dejw it's the shortest one which works on not only create

Comment: Thank You for explanation. Nevertheless klew's answer was shorter ;-)

Comment: @Dejw: @klew's answer is correct in that it'll fail validation when the fields are equal, but it forgets to flag both of the problematic fields.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Create custom validataion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods):

```
validate :check_email_and_password

def check_email_and_password
  errors.add(:password, "can't be the same as email") if email == password
end
```

But keep in mind that storing password as a plain text is bad idea. You should store it hashed. Try some authentication plugin like [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) or [Restful authentication](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/restful_authentication).

Answer (score 17):

New way:

```
validates :password, exclusion: { in: lambda{ |user| [user.email] } }
```

or:

```
validates :password, exclusion: { in: ->(user) { [user.email] } }
```

Comment: PLease clarify what you mean by "new way". Which ruby/rails is this applied?

Comment: It worked at least from Rails 3.2.22 / Ruby 2.2.6 - excellent short solution. Thanks.

Comment: This is the right answer, as it uses an existing api, and you don't need to roll out your own custom validation! +1

Answer (score 6):

You can use a custom validation method to check this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def validate
    if (self.email == self.password)
      errors.add(:password, "password cannot equal email")
      errors.add(:email, "email cannot equal password")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends how Your password is stored:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :email_and_password_validation

    def email_and_password_validation
        if self.email == self.password
            errors.add_to_base("Password must be different from email") 
        end
    end
end
```

This would work if Your password is stored literally, but You can perform the same thing with email (e.g. create a hashed version) and check for equality with password. E.g:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :email_and_password_validation

    def email_and_password_validation
        if make_hash(self.email) == self.hashed_password
            errors.add_to_base("Password must be different from email") 
        end
    end
end
```

My example is taken from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002162

Your situation is quite general so You can be interested in creating custom validation method. Everything is covered here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods

Comment: Fixed link (taken from old version of Rails Guides). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

it is much wiser to use custom validator, here is code for universal validator that can be used

```rb
class ValuesNotEqualValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if options[:fields].any? && options[:fields].size >= 2
      field_values = options[:fields].collect { |f| record.send(f) }
      unless field_values.size == field_values.uniq.size
        record.errors[:base] <<
            (options[:msg].blank? ? "fields: #{options[:fields].join(", ")} - should not be equal" :
                options[:msg])
      end
    else
      raise "#{self.class.name} require at least two fields as options [e.g. fields: [:giver_id, :receiver_id]"
    end
  end
end
```

and then use it like:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validates_with ValuesNotEqualValidator, fields: [:email, :password], msg: "This Person is evil"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Ruby on Rails 7.0 added support for [`validates_comparison_of`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#comparison)   validations like this

```
validates :password, comparison: { other_than: :email }
```

Answer (score 2):

more fun:

```rb
  validates :password, exclusion: { in: ->(person) { [person.email] }, message: "cannot use protected password" }
```

which might be even better in this case, since you could check for other forbidden values with something like

```rb
  validates :password, exclusion: { in: ->(person) { [person.email, person.first_name, person.last_name, person.phone_number, person.department_name] }, message: "cannot use protected password" }
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to create validation rule in your model
for example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def validate_on_create
    if email == password
      errors.add("password", "email and password can't be the same")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. We want `validate`, not `validate_on_create`, because we need to check on all saves that the e-mail isn't the password (not just at creation time).

Comment: There is a syntax error (typo) in error message: You cannot use single quote marks in string which is single quoted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support multiple languages, you have to come up with another solution, which translates the error messages and the attribute names. So I created a new each validator for that.

`validators/values_not_equal_validator.rb`:

```
class ValuesNotEqualValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate(record)
    @past = Hash.new
    super
  end

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    @past.each do |k, v|
      if v == value
        record.errors.add(attribute, I18n.t('errors.messages.should_not_be_equal_to') + " " + record.class.human_attribute_name(k))
      end
    end
    @past[attribute] = value
  end
end
```

I call it in the model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :forename, :surname, values_not_equal: true
end
```

And I translate it the messages like this:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        forename: 'Vorname'
        surname: 'Nachname'
  errors:
    messages:
      should_not_be_equal_to: 'darf nicht gleich sein wie'
```

Answer (score 0):

By using custom validations we can do this operation

validate :validate_address

def validate_address
  errors.add(:permenent_address, "can't be the same as present_address") if self.present_address== self.permenent_address
end