# find_by_sql in Rails for custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby on rails, I used scaffold two times like this

```
rails g scaffold userpost user_field1:string user_field2:string
rails g scaffold adminpost admin_field1:string admin_field2:string
```

I want to make a custom validation When users post userpost.

Users can post only userpost. Admin can post only adminpost. And user can post user_field1 same as admin_field1 and user_field2 same as admin_field2.

I tried this code

```
class Userpost < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :check_userpost

  def check_userpost
    admin_field2 = Adminpost.find_by_sql ("SELECT admin_field2 FROM adminposts WHERE admin_field1 = '#{self.user_field1}'")
    if admin_field2 != '#{self.user_field2}'
      errors.add(:user_field2, "not match")
    end
  end
end
```

If you have any ideas, please give me advises.

Comment: The `#{variable}` syntax is only applied on `"double quotes"` not `'single quotes'`. Might be worth noting.

Comment: I tried this also
`def check_userpost
    admin_field2 = Adminpost.find_by_sql ("SELECT admin_field2 FROM adminposts WHERE admin_field1 = #{self.user_field1}")
    if admin_field2 != "#{self.user_field2}"
      errors.add(:user_field2, "not match")
    end
  end`
it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference to: [How do I validate that two values do not equal each other in a Rails model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273122/how-do-i-validate-that-two-values-do-not-equal-each-other-in-a-rails-model)

Observable differences:

1. "validate" not "validates"
2. why use SQL when you can use ActiveRecord?

   ```
   class Userpost < ActiveRecord::Base
     validate :check_userpost

     def check_userpost
       tmp = Adminpost.find_by_admin_field1(self.user_field1)
       if tmp and tmp.admin_field2 != self.user_field2
         errors.add(:user_field2, "not match") 
       end
     end
   end
   ```

Taking a wild stab by doing some googling....

Comment: @Mitsunobuk you should probably look at model associations though... the validation should be possible through self.adminpost since there's already some assocation in table: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Very nice advise. 
I made what I want. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping there is no relation between userpost and adminpost.

```
def check_userpost
  af1 = Adminpost.where(admin_field1: self.user_field1).first
  af2 = Adminpost.where(admin_field2: self.user_field2).first
  if !af1.nil? && af1.admin_field2 != self.user_feild2
    errors.add(:user_field2, "not match")        
  end
  if !af2.nil? && af2.admin_field1 != self.user_feild1
    errors.add(:user_field1, "not match")        
  end
end
```

Comment: Thx your comment. I got solved it.
I'm glad you to comment.