# custom validator on a couple of attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in trouble with Rails 'Validator'
I have a table `FollowingRelationship` to store a couple of user, in which I should validate that `follower_id != followed_id` (user can't follows themselves).

This is my model:

```
class FollowingRelationship < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true, followed_id: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :follower_id, scope: :followed_id 

  class FollowedValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      record.errors.add attribute, "User can't follow itselves" unless record.follower_id != value
    end
  end
end
```

but the validator still not work

`FollowingRelationship.create(:follower_id => 1, :followed_id => 1)` shouldn't create the record, but it works.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2273122/477037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a custom validator class is a bit much for a single method validation (unless it needs to be used in multiple models).  Try this

```
class FollowingRelationship < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true, followed_id: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :follower_id, scope: :followed_id
  validate  :does_not_follow_self

  def does_not_follow_self
    self.errors.add attribute, "User can't follow itself" unless self.follower != self.followed
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a validator like this for my facebook clone.

you can find it [here](https://github.com/Khanthulhu/The-Dog-Park/blob/master/app/models/friend_request.rb).

The basic version looks like this

```
    def stop_friending_yourself
        errors.add(:user_id, "can't friend themself") if user_id == friend_id
    end
```